# What other alternatives do I have for nested if statements for float variables going to infinity?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, infinity

I'm trying to construct a code for a `float` variables that does not rely on nested if statements unlike you can see in the following code-example.

As you can see the higher the velocity of the ball, the longer the code would get.

Is there a shorter way to write the code or do I have to use the nested if-else statement for the variable of ball_vector_x when going up to infinity or just as example up to 100?

counter is an `int` variable starting at zero

```
if(ball_vector_x == 4 || ball_vector_x == -4) {
    counter = 1;
  } else if(ball_vector_x == 5 || ball_vector_x == -5) {
    counter = 2;
  } else if(ball_vector_x == 6 || ball_vector_x == -6) {
    counter = 3;
  } else if(ball_vector_x == 7 || ball_vector_x == -7) {
    counter = 4;
  } else if(ball_vector_x == 8 || ball_vector_x == -8) {
    counter = 5;
  } else if(ball_vector_x == 9 || ball_vector_x == -9) {
    counter = 6;
  } else if(ball_vector_x == 10 || ball_vector_x == -10) {
    counter = 7;
  } else if(ball_vector_x == 11 || ball_vector_x == -11) {
    counter = 8;
  } else if(ball_vector_x == 12 || ball_vector_x == -12) {
    counter = 9;
  } else if(ball_vector_x == 13 || ball_vector_x == -13) {
    counter = 10;
```

Comment: Your question is more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or maybe code golf

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions: `ball_vector_x` should be `ballVectorX`.

Answer (score 7):

It seems your counter is always vector - 3. Can't you do this

```
  counter = Math.abs(ball_vector_x)-3;
```

Comment: Note that this isn't quite the same. For example, what would OP's code do for an input of 4.5, vs what this code would do.

Comment: I cannot use this one cause I declared ball_vector_x as a `float` variable

Comment: @Philzen and Andy - since this piece of code doesn't provide any motivation to declare `ball_vector_x` as a float - it should be regarded as an `int` and this answer is perfectly valid. Examples like 4.5 are not. Andy - you can also compare imaginary numbers ... but why would you do that ???

Comment: @alfasin well, at least the OP knows about floats, and makes it clear the he is working with those. I think that is one of the problems why this answer caused that churn, simply because there are various implicit things going on that could have been made explicit.

Answer (score 1):

First: you can use Math.abs() to cut the number of comparisons by half.

And then you could use a map to store all these pairs for example.

But of course, the real answer is: you can express the relationship between those values using a simple formula. That is *always* the solution to look out for.

Finally: the point that the other answers are missing to explain -avoid comparing floating point numbers using ==. Use epsilon based comparison instead.

Answer (score -1):

This will check if ball_vector_x is negative or positive and then set counter equal to the value of i.

```
if (ball_vector_x >= 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ball_vector_x; i++) {
        if(i == ball_vector_x) {
             counter = i - 3;
        }
    }
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i > ball_vector_x; i--) {
             if (i == ball_vector_x) {
                counter = (-1)*(i + 3); // I might've done the calculation       wrong here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It ain't working right. the counter is always at zero

Comment: Due to your loop conditions, the condition of the `if` can never be true.